# Datagridview cell.value =DatagridviewComboboxCell.value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to see whatever I see in my comboboxcell in other cell only for the current row I'm trying something like this with no result:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = 
   dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value;\\ cell  1 is my comboboxcell
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a class named with Item to add items in List,

**Item class;**

```
public class Item
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }
```

In Form_Load, I loaded datagridview,

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("test1", "test1");
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn testCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            testCol.HeaderText = "comboValues";
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(testCol);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("test2", "test1");
            List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
            items.Add(new Item() { Name = "One", Id = 1 });
            items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Two", Id = 2 }); // created two Items 
            var cbo = dataGridView1.Columns[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn; // index of 1 is the comboboxColumn
            cbo.DataSource = items; // setting datasource 
            cbo.ValueMember = "Id";
            cbo.DisplayMember = "Name";
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("", items[1].Id, "test1");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("", items[0].Id, "test2");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("", items[1].Id, "test3"); // and test rows
        }
```

We need to check which row is the previous one before new selection, so we need to use Row_Leave event.

```
int previousRowIndex = 0; // a variable to keep the index of row
        private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            previousRowIndex = e.RowIndex;
        }
```

And the main event is SelectionChanged,

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[previousRowIndex].Cells[0].Value = ""; // first set the previous row's first cell value empty string.
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboCell = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell; 
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = comboCell.EditedFormattedValue; // then set the first cell's value as the combobox's selected value.
        }
```

**Result;**

[image: dgv row selection]

Hope helps,